# Cheapest way to find the oldest file (recursively) from a directory under heavy load

Tags: files, find, directory, ls, fifo

What is the least expensive way to find the oldest file in a directory, including all directories underneath.  Assume directory is backed by SAN and under heavy load.

There is concern that "ls" could be locking and cause system degradation under heavy load.

Edit: Find performs very well under a simple test case - find oldest file amongst 400 gigs of files on an SSD drive took 1/20 seconds.  But this is a MacBook Pro Laptop under no load... So it's a bit of an apples to oranges test case.

And as an aside what is the best way to find out implementations (underlying algorithms) for such commands?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to list files that were changed in a certain range of time?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29245/how-to-list-files-that-were-changed-in-a-certain-range-of-time)

Comment: @jasonwryan No, knowing what files were modified in a given time range doesn't help to find the oldest file.

Comment: `ls` doesn't scan the file contents. It reads the directories and `stat`s the files, which is necessary to find the oldest files anyway. But `ls` won't really help you because going from any `ls` output to finding the oldest files would be very difficult.

Comment: I am surprised nobody mentioned using an event driven model to accomplish this... ie building something that uses inotify.

Answer (score 2):

With `zsh`:

```
oldest=(**/*(.DOm[1]))
```

For the oldest regular file (`zsh` time resolution is to the second)

With GNU tools:

```
(export LC_ALL=C
 find . -type f -printf '%T@\t%p\0' |
   sort -zg | tr '\0\n' '\n\0' | head -n 1 |
   cut -f2- | tr '\0' '\n')
```

Comment: +1 Perhaps add something about backgrounding this and `nice`ing it as the user seems worried about it locking and affecting performance under heavy load.

Comment: @JosephR. `nice`ing? Useless, this is IO-bound. `ionice`, maybe.

Comment: @Gilles Please correct me if I'm wrong. Wouldn't both `nice` and `ionice` be relevant here? The `find` would take up CPU and can therefore benefit from `nice` and the `rm` would need lots of I/O and would therefore benefit from `ionice`.

Comment: @JosephR. `find` is IO-bound just like RM. The CPU time needed to format the data is negligible compared to the `stat` calls.

Answer (score 0):

To minimize the number of external processes, you may be able to optimize by running a custom script instead of a proper `find`.  The directory traversal and `stat()` of each file cannot be optimized away, but you only need to keep the oldest file so far in memory.

Here is an attempt in Perl:

```
find2perl -eval 'BEGIN { our ($filename, $oldest); }
    my @s=stat(_); if (! defined $::oldest || $s[9] < $::oldest) {
        $::oldest=$s[9]; $::filename = $File::Find::name }
    END { print "$::filename\n" }' | perl
```

In my tests, on a moderately large directory (129019 nodes), this is actually about 50% slower than @StephaneChazelas "GNU Tools" version, but you may find that it works better in some scenarios, especially for really large directories.

Comment: If you prefer Python, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7541863/python-equivalent-of-find2perl has some hints.