# how to find specific type of file that are modified within a certain range of dates

Tags: search, file-search

There are many questions here that seek files modified within a certain date range.

How do we use linux (Ubuntu) command line to search for a certain type (e.g. *.odt) file within a certain date range?

Comment: What specifically do you want to know that is not already covered in the previous questions, for example [How to list files that were changed in a certain range of time?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/29245/how-to-list-files-that-were-changed-in-a-certain-range-of-time)

Comment: how to search for a type of file---like a pdf file--- within a date range

Comment: You can add a simple filename-based condition like `-iname '*.pdf'`. If that is not sufficient, please see [How to find files by file type?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/483871/how-to-find-files-by-file-type)